# Show other answers in Low Quality Review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Often times the problem with an answer isn't apparent unless it is shown in context. I've run into more than a few answers in VLQ review that are thank you comments, or are duplicate answers, but it isn't immediately apparent because the other answers aren't shown in review.

Can all of the answers be be displayed when reviewing?

I've searched through meta.stackexchange and meta.stackoverflow and I'm a little surprised that this hasn't been asked before... If it has please point me to the original.

Related: [Review first post / late answers: show other answers as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174445/review-first-post-late-answers-show-other-answers-as-well)

Comment: MSE -> [See other answers in Low Quality Posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144259/165773) :)

Comment: @gnat [D'oh!](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/D%27oh?file=D%2527oh.jpg) Thanks.

Comment: 2 reviewers (including myself) just got caught by this in less than one hour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62221447/9210961). I agree that it would be an improvement. Granted, there is a link to the original post. But because it is faded, the whole page design is not encouraging naive reviewers (such as myself) to follow it. I did do this every now and then, but I did not realize that it was expected of me to do it each time. Now I will know better, but I think that many other reviewers will make the same mistake and a different design would prevent this.